# plot performance MSE, RMSE

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This dataframe as explained below consists of 4 methods and 3 performance measures for each method. I want to have a  barplot for each method similar as this:

[image]

```
              Method      MSE   RMSE    MAE
            Baseline 42674.68 206.58 149.96
   Linear Regression 10738.56 103.63  55.85
       Random forest  4492.47  67.03  37.29
      Neural Network  7650.72  87.47  57.50
```

However, I am not able to obtain this with ggplot or something similar. Can someone help me?

Comment: It's not worth changing it this time, but for future reference it's best to share data with `dput` or if you're not going to do that, at least don't include line numbers. It makes it harder for us to get it into R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read in your data

```
dd = read.table(textConnection("Method MSE RMSE MAE
Baseline 42674.68 206.58 149.96
LinearRegression 10738.56 103.63  55.85
Randomforest  4492.47  67.03  37.29
NeuralNetwork  7650.72  87.47  57.50"), header=TRUE)
```

Next we need to reshape your data frame to be ggplot2 friendly using `reshape2`

```
dd_m = reshape2::melt(dd, c("Method"))

head(dd_m, 2)
#            Method variable value
#1         Baseline      MSE 42675
#2 LinearRegression      MSE 10739
```

Then we use `geom_bar`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd_m) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Method), 
              stat="identity", # Don't transform the data
              position = "dodge") # Dodge the bars
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe for improvement of the readability, I should scale MSE